# Trigger another WF when current = Approved

Tags: designer-workflow

I'd like some help with a reminder workflow to start when another workflow is Approved and not before.

I can`t get it to work. I'm using SharePoint OOTB Approval Workflow. I've also created a Workflow Reminder that also works like it should, but now I need it start when Approval Workflow = Approved.

The only thing I've added is the If statement and Wait for Approval Workflow equals Approved. I do not get my email now. The log stops after the 3rd row

[image]

Comment: Can you add a log statement after Pause and see is it still in pause state and also verify the Workflow status is Completed or started.

Comment: Pause in Stage 1? I did that and it's the last log and just stops after that. It adds the 2 minutes and nothing happens afterwards. Yes workflow status is Started and the 'Last run'is same as the 'Started' time.

Comment: Can you log the pause date before it go into pause.

Comment: Sorry Venkat. This is what i got in the log

Workflow started at: 5/23/2017 2:40:47 PM

Item was uploaded on: 5/23/2017 2:41:07 PM

Paused until: 5/23/2017 2:43:07 PM

Pause (this is pause in stage 2)

after that it just starts over

Answer (score 0):

Here two things I would suggest:
1) Make sure your other workflow kicks off this workflow once it is approved.
2) The statement 'wait for approval workflow to equal approved' should go before if statement clause.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with suggestion 1 because I just started doing workflows and it's pretty hard to get a hang of. I tried doing the second suggestion and changed place like you said but it is not working.

Comment: Suggestion 1 Details: There is an action in the workflow that allows you to start another workflow. You can use that option.

Comment: Suggestion 2 Details: See the workflow log what happens if you move the 'Wait for approval workflow to equal approved' statement before if clause. Make sure that step is executing.